# Custom .is_a? in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to create a custom `is_a?` in Ruby?

I have a string that can be either a UID or a nickname that I need to check and decide.

UID: `001ABC123` (starts with 3 numeric and ends in 6 alphanumeric characters)

Nickname: `john` (can be anything but never starts with a number)

I want to be able to do:

```
t = '001ABC123'

if t.is_a? UID
  ...
end
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Adding `is_a` globally to String is a pretty bad idea. If anywhere else in the project someone else decides to also add an `is_a` method to String - you will get some interesting bugs.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for succinct way of doing the check, why not use regular expression and match using `=~` operator.

This is as neat as using custom `is_a?` and does not require messing up with `String` class.

For example:

```
UID = /^[[:digit:]]{3}[[:alnum:]]{6}$/

t = '001ABC123'

if t =~ UID
   #...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to pollute global `String` - use refinements:

```
class UID < String
end

module CustomStringIsA
  refine String do
    def is_a? what
      if what == UID
        self == '123'
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

puts '123'.is_a?(UID) # false

using CustomStringIsA
puts '123'.is_a?(Fixnum) # false
puts '123'.is_a?(UID) # true
```

But better use `===`, so you can then use `case` like this:

```
class UID < String
  def self.=== str
    str === '123'
  end
end

class UID2 < String
  def self.=== str
    str === '456'
  end
end

case '456'
when UID
  puts 'uid'
when UID2
  puts 'uid2'
else
  puts 'else'
end
```

Answer (score -2):

One of the great things about ruby is that you may reopen any class. So an implementation of this may look like this:

```
class String
    def is_a?(type)
        return true if type == UID
    end
end
```

Comment: This solution returns `nil` for `'string'.is_a?(String)`, which is supposed to be `true` and most probably will break something in 3rd party libraries